# Get serial number from Show inventory

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, grep

I would like to get the `device ID` and `Serial Number` of a cisco device from `show inventory` command, I've got the terminal output in a file that looks like this:

```
show inventory
NAME: "1", DESCR: "WS-C3750G-12S"
PID: WS-C3750G-12S-E   , VID: V06, SN: FDO1129Z9ZJ

NAME: "GigabitEthernet1/0/1", DESCR: "1000BaseLX SFP"
PID:                     , VID:    , SN: H006K022        

NAME: "GigabitEthernet1/0/2", DESCR: "10/100/1000BaseTX SFP"
PID: GLC-T               , VID:    , SN: 00000MTC1444080Z

NAME: "GigabitEthernet1/0/3", DESCR: "1000BaseLX SFP"
PID:                     , VID:    , SN: H006K083        

NAME: "GigabitEthernet1/0/4", DESCR: "1000BaseLX SFP"
PID:                     , VID:    , SN: H006K021        

NAME: "GigabitEthernet1/0/5", DESCR: "1000BaseSX SFP"
PID:                     , VID:    , SN: FNS11190FLE     

NAME: "GigabitEthernet1/0/6", DESCR: "1000BaseSX SFP"
PID:                     , VID:    , SN: P7K08UQ         

NAME: "GigabitEthernet1/0/7", DESCR: "1000BaseLX SFP"
PID:                     , VID:    , SN: H006K032        

NAME: "GigabitEthernet1/0/8", DESCR: "1000BaseLX SFP"
PID:                     , VID:    , SN: H006K040        

NAME: "GigabitEthernet1/0/9", DESCR: "1000BaseLX SFP"
PID:                     , VID:    , SN: FNS14420533     

NAME: "GigabitEthernet1/0/10", DESCR: "1000BaseLX SFP"
PID: GLC-LH-SMD          , VID: V86, SN: FNS16361SG0     

NAME: "GigabitEthernet1/0/11", DESCR: "1000BaseLX SFP"
PID: GLC-LH-SMD          , VID: V86, SN: FNS174002FT     

NAME: "GigabitEthernet1/0/12", DESCR: "1000BaseLX SFP"
PID: GLC-LH-SMD          , VID: V86, SN: FNS183503FS     


Barragan_3750>
```

I would like to get the `SN` of the device called "1" and the `device name` that is behind ">", something like this:

```
Barragan_3750
SN: FDO1129Z9ZJ
```

thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Do you mean `WS-C3750G-12S` and `FDO1129Z9ZJ` for the entry with name `1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU `sed`:

```
$ show inventory | sed -n '/^NAME: "1"/,+1s/^.*, //p'
DESCR: "WS-C3750G-12S"
SN: FDO1129Z9ZJ
```

The `sed` editing script will look for lines starting with `NAME "1"` and apply a substitution to those lines and the first immediately following line.

The substitution will remove everything on the lines up to and including the last comma (and the space just after). The resulting strings are printed to the terminal.

If it's only the serial number and the last line of output you want:

```
$ show inventory | sed -n -e '/^NAME: "1"/{n;s/^.*, //p}' -e '$p'
SN: FDO1129Z9ZJ
Barragan_3750>
```

Here, the `sed` script finds the line as before, but immediately reads the next line (with `n`) and performs the same substitution as before only on that line.  This gives you the serial number.

Then it prints the last line of the input too.

Answer (score 1):

Use blank lines as record separator.

If the line matches ' "1", ' save the last field.

Print the last line without the last character and print the saved field.

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS = ""}
     { if ($0 ~/ "1", /) { serial=$NF } }
     END { print substr($0, 1, length($0)-1) ; print "SN: " serial }' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
show inventory | perl -l -00ane '
  /^NAME:\s+"1",/m and $serial_num = "@F[-2,-1]";
  print substr($_,0,-1), $\, $serial_num if eof;
'
```

A brief summary of the above:

To set the stage stated are the `Perl` options utilized.
We operate Perl in the `paragraph mode` `-00` AND also auto-split mode `-a` whereby each para is then split up on spaces to populate the `@F` array each time a new paragraph is read in.

This is what the `Perl's $_` looks like after gulping down one para:

NAME: "1", DESCR: "WS-C3750G-12S"

PID: WS-C3750G-12S-E   , VID: V06, SN: FDO1129Z9ZJ

IOW, `$_` holds a paragraph. Then this `$_` is split up on `\s+` like this:
`@F = split /\s+/, $_;`
This results in the `@F` array , stating from reverse:
  `$F[-1] = 'FDO1129Z9ZJ'; $F[-2] = 'SN:' ...`

`And mind you , all of the above happens under the hood`. Once that is taken care of we come to the code of the Perl snippet:
`/^NAME:\s+"`",/m => will return true for a `record aka para aka $_` when it begins with `NAME...` or begins with `NAME...` on a `newline` due to the pattern modifier `/m` standing for `for multiple-line matching`. For that we get the serial number of the as the last field `$F[-1]` of this para and grab the string `SN:` as the second-last field `$F[-2]`. Now we can extract them in one fell swoop like as `@F[-2,-1]` and put them under double quotes like as `"@F[-2,-1]"` implying `"$F[-2]" space "$F[-1]"` something along the lines of that famous shell variable `"$@"`. Meaning we get a space-separated list of array elements. To be accurate, it is the `$" superglobal`, whose value acts as the separator, just like the first character in `IFS` determines the double-quoted interpolation of `"$*"` in `bash`.

Now we have our `serial number` of the device, we go look for the `device number` which is to be found the `last record` aka `eof`. Here the `substr($_,0,-1)` takes the `$_` aka `para` and removes `1` char starting from the end of `-1` that's what the `-` signifies and returns after removing and concatenates the `serial_number` already determined with the `$\` which is stuffed with a `\n` due to the `-l` option. This is finally printed on stdout.

Hope I was not very confusing & HTH.

Comment: As perl is rather obscure language for some - could you please explain how that works?

Comment: @DarkHeart. Done.